# Error parsing website template the extension [.zip|.css|.template] is not allowed - DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to create a new portal from a template in a DNN (v7.1). If I check "Include Files?" option during template export and use that template I receive the error below right after click "Create Portal":

> Error parsing website template the extension [.zip|.css|.template] is
>   not allowed.

The extension in the error message changes on each try; ***.zip, .css and .template*** are the ones I received so far. The new portal gets created but does not work (gives server error) after receiving the error.

It happens only if I check "Include Files?" option during template export.

I upgraded to 7.2.1 in a test environment, but didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Check that these file types are allowed in DNN. Go to Host -> Host Settings -> Other Settings and under 'Allowable File Types', make sure the extensions css,zip,template are in the list.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I added the extensions and the error message is different now.

`Error parsing Website TemplatePage Exists in portal: 15, path: , culture: `

Comment: Ah, I've had this happen to me as well. What that error is saying is that a tab name already exists for one that your template is trying to add. Either there are 2 tabs with the same name in your template, DNN has partially created the portal on a failed attempt so there are duplicate tabs for the same portal. Also check your template isn't trying to add admin tabs. The template is an XML file.